# Designing a system in which user can give access to tasks

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, nestjs, typeorm

I am designing a small system in which there will be two models ( currently ).

- User
- Task

Users can create tasks. And can invite another user to a task and give him access as a read-only or read-write. I am able to create the models for each of them but I am not able to figure out the relationships related to user access.

here are my models

```
// user.entity.ts

@Entity()
@Unique(['email'])
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  first_name: string;

  @Column()
  last_name: string;

  @Exclude()
  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Task, (task) => task.user, { eager: true })
  task: Task[];
}
```

```
// task.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Task extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @Exclude()
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.task, { eager: false })
  user: User;

  @Column()
  userId: number;
}
```

I am pretty new to databases and models. I thought of creating an entity that would have task_id, user_id, access_role as columns, but I am not able to move forward from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe a M:M relationship between User:Task. These type relationships are typically resolved with a intersection table - your thought of another entity is dead on. In this case perhaps User_Task table. Intersection tables often contain attributes related to that combination. Here that would be the authorization the user has on the task. So here something like: (assuming user_id is PK to User table and task_id is PK to Task table and each are integers:  ( Sorry I have to give just SQL as I do not know your obfuscation layer -  TypeORM?)

```
create table user_task
       ( user_id integer    
       , task_id integer
       , access  text  constraint access_ck check (access in ('RO', 'RW'))
       , constraint user_task_pk 
                    primary key (user_id, task_id) 
       , constraint user_task_2_user_fk 
                    foreign key (user_id)
                    references users(user_id) 
       , constraint user_task_2_task_fk 
                    foreign key (task_id)
                    references tasks(task_id) 
       );
```

The above describes the minimal case, now for the hard part. That involves your design:

Consider Task_1 only:

- Can a user invite themself? How does the first user get assigned to a
  task?
- When user_a invites user_b, does user_a have any further influence or effect
  on user_b to task relationship. If so what?
- Can user_b now invite user_c?  Anytime, or dependent on access.
- What happens when user_a invites user_c and later user_b invites
  user_c?
- What happens in the above when the access is different.

I am sure there could be many others. The answer to above could change the table columns.